# Add multi dimension object in ng-init in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ng-init

I want to add multi dimension object in ng-init like

```js
object({
    friends:[
        {name:John,phone:555-1276},
        {name:Mary,phone:800-BIG-MARY},
        {name:Mike,phone:555-4321},
        {name:Adam,phone:555-5678},
        {name:Julie,phone:555-8765},
        {name:Juliette,phone:555-5678}
   ],
   relative:[
       {name:Afaq,phone:555-1276},
       {name:Mary,phone:800-BIG-MARY},
       {name:Mike,phone:555-4321},
       {name:Adam,phone:555-5678},
       {name:Julie,phone:555-8765},
       {name:Juliette,phone:555-5678}
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but when i add same like this then show me this error

"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Carrara' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 1754 of the expression [object("

so what to do....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your object structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object structure is wrong. Try this

```js
 var x = {
  "parent": {
   "friends": [{
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    }
   ],
   "relative": [{
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
     "name": "John",
     "phone": "555 - 1276"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
 console.log(x);
```

You can always use [Json lint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your json

Comment: ok but i want all add in one parent just like this

parent{
"friends": [{
        "name": "John",
        "phone": "555 - 1276"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "phone": "555 - 1276"
    }
],
"relative": [{
        "name": "John",
        "phone": "555 - 1276"
    }
 ]
}

is it possible ?

Comment: you mean all that as single object ? if yes, that's what it is already

Comment: yes but when i add parent as a single and validate on json init it showing errorError: Parse error on line 1:
"parent" { {  "friends": [{
---------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got '{'

Comment: let me know if you still confused